# Images not showing when using Github pages. Vite + react

Tags: reactjs, github-pages, vite

I simply cant get the images to render whatever I do. I think I might have messed up since I tried to deploy on both netlify and vercel without it even showing the page so I went back to github pages.I dont know what is safe to remove from package.json and if I even need to.

I have tried many different locations for the images and referencing them in different ways but I cant get it to work. Sometimes the site does not work, but when it does the images wont show. . or ./ or images/.. dont make a difference. I've been trying since yesterday and also waited around an hour to see if it just takes a while for it to update. The last thing I've tried now was to put the images directly into the public folder instead of a images folder inside of it.

This is my first time trying to deploy something that isnt vanilla html and javascript so I have a hard time finding the solution.

Repo:
https://github.com/Jesper-Lindstrom/portfolio

Comment: For the vercel I think it's not working because you have your `base` in your vite config set to `/portfolio/` but your vercel hosted on `/`.

Comment: I stopped trying with vercel since I only got a white screen. Do you mean to change the root folder? Because there arent many other settings.

Comment: Can you try to use vercel and set the `base` in vite config to `/`?

Comment: I will try right away

edit: IT WORKS! Finally. Thank you so much. Images and everything seems fine now :)